# How to anonymize an Apache log after the fact?

Tags: http, privacy

I encountered a bug in an open source PHP program and I want to create a bug report. I expect that the server log will be important for the developers (as a minimum, it is needed to prove that there is a bug and not user error). The log on the server is "pure", and contains valid user IP addresses of my users.

I looked around for anonymization, but all results I found were about anonymizing on-the-fly and not keeping IPs on the server. But this doesn't apply to my situation.

I found a [script](http://www.stephencuppett.com/wordpress/2008/06/03/web-log-anonymizer/) which promises to do what I need. Sadly, it doesn't work - the output is a file containing the single string `ORIG` instead of a log with random IP addresses. I don't know Perl, so I can't troubleshoot it.

Any ideas how to get my data anonymized? The whole log file is just a list of HTTP requests and responses, one per line. I don't care if I use something else than the script above, or if you can point out what the problem is with it.

Answer (score 2):

To fix that script, you need to change `while (< ORIG >) {` to `while (<ORIG>) {`.

Note that that script takes a bit of a sledgehammer approach - it will replace *any* sequence of four numbers of any length separated by dots, not just IP addresses. In other words, it will match `124.4534653.74623.0`, `1.1.1.1`, `http://example.com/foo/1.2.3.42345446/bar` and more. If this is an issue for you, then you will need to identify which column of your log contains IP addresses and write a slightly more complicated script that modifies that column only.

---

Fixed script included to keep this Q&A self-contained, credit to [Stephen Cuppet](http://www.stephencuppett.com/wordpress/2008/06/03/web-log-anonymizer/).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
if ($#ARGV + 1 < 1) {
        print "\n\tUsage:\n";
        print "\t------\n\n";
        print "\tperl log_anonymize.pl file1 [file2 [file3 [...]]]\n\n";
        die "Please specify at least one file to use this script.\n\n";
}

my %forward = ();
my %reverse = ();

foreach (@ARGV) {
        open(ORIG, $_)
          or die "Failed to open input file for reading.";
        open(ANON, "+>", $_.".anon")
          or die "Failed to open destination file for writing.";
        while (<ORIG>) {
                if (/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/) {
                        if (!($forward->{$1})) {
                                $newIp = getNewIp();
                                while ($reverse->{$newIp}) {
                                        $newIp = getNewIp();
                                }
                                print "New mapping created: $1 -> $newIp\n";
                                $forward->{$1} = $newIp;
                                $reverse->{$newIp} = $1;
                        }
                        $repl = $forward->{$1};
                        $_ =~ s/$1/$repl/;
                }
                print ANON $_;
        }
        close(ORIG);
        close(ANON);
}

exit 0;

sub getNewIp {
        return int(rand(256)) . "." . int(rand(256)) . "." . int(rand(256)) . "." . int(rand(256));
}
```